# Can i filter records in a report with a criteria similar to limit n on SOQL?

Tags: reporting, filters

I have a report pulling out multiple child records, grouped by parent, where i want just the first child record based on created date/time.   In  SOQL i would use "order by CreatedDate and limit 1".  Is there a similar thing i could do in reports to limit the child records?

Comment: If a tabular report is used, A dashboard can be used to limit the number of records shown there.  In this scenario, a limit can be set on the report. Its not an answer but is a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The Report Builder does not provide a LIMIT option. This will require doing your report through other means, whether a Visualforce page with SOQL or exporting the data to a different system.

You may be able to find something in the AppExchange.

Comment: my 2cents, I have used a program called Talend to write some pretty simple reports to excel. It may be a bit of overkill though. It is eclipse based so if you are used to ForceIDE it isn't the toughest thing to get a handle on.

Comment: Thanks,  I'm aware of talend.   I too believe its an overkill.   We need something simpler than Visualforce Reports and Out of the Box.